# Django Queryset creating a .values() based on the sorting of another field

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-aggregation

I'm trying to the most likely predicted category for a datapoint. Since code is the best explanation:

models:

```
class DataPoint(models.Model):
    #... unimportant fields

class PredResult(models.Model):
    likelihood = models.FloatField()
    value = models.IntegerField()
    data_point = models.ForeignKey(DataPoint)
```

For each DataPoint object I am trying to find the `value` for the PredResult with the highest likelihood. Currently I'm using a for-loop:

```
data_points = DataPoints.objects.select_related('predresult')
for dp in data_points:
    if dp.predresult_set.all().exists():
        val = dp.predresult_set.order_by('-likelihood')[0].value
        #do other stuff here with val and dp
```

I'd like to get add a `best_value` field to the `DataPoint` queryset. Currently there are ~5 PredResult objects per DataPoint and ~20,000 DataPoints (although this may balloon rapidly). However, this for-loop takes too long to complete within a view.

Can anyone suggest a way to deal with this? Either a Django ORM trick, a `extra()` method on the `Queryset`. Or do you think I should use a `post-save` method on the `PredResult` object and update a field on the `DataPoint` object directly?

If its needed I'm using MySQL as the database backend.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregation:

```
from django.db.models import Max
values = DataPoint.objects.annotate(max_result=Max('predresult__value'))
```

Now each element in `values` has a `max_result` attribute containing the max related result.

Comment: not quite what I'm looking for. That will give the largest `value` ... I need the `value` with the largest `likelihood`.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be `Max('predresult__likelihood')`, then?

Comment: Then I would only get the largest `likelihood`. I need the value that has the largest likelihood.